# Remove hyphen(-) symbol between graph and numbers

Tags: javascript, bar-chart

Remove Hypehen(-) symbol in the bar charts

Answer (score 0):

Use stemColor: 'none', Example:

```
annotations: {
  alwaysOutside: true,
  stemColor: 'none',
  stemLength: 2,
  textStyle: {
   auraColor: 'none',
   color: '#000',
   fontSize: 12
  }
}
```